# Detect click only on highlighted portion of the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to detect click on the highlighted portion of the textarea and a modal needs to popup with highlighted text.[Screenshot of the selected word in the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYJI8.png)

Here I need to detect if a click happens on the word 'community'.Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is causing the word to be highlighted? Is the user manually doing this?

Comment: @adam-beck yes, the user is manually highlighting it.

Comment: The DOM does not create a special wrapper around highlighted text. So there isn't anything given to you for free you can attach a click listener on. Off the top of my head you'll need to get the user selection with `window.getSelection()`. Then wrap that text with a DOM element. Then add a click listener to that element. And make sure to remove it 
 (the new DOM element) when it's no longer highlighted.

Comment: @adam-beck is it possible to wrap the highlighted text inside **textarea** with a DOM element. ?

Comment: As @adam-beck suggested, you could start from the `window.getSelection()` object, although it is not really cross-browser. Just to begin, you could find whether the clicked element is included in the selection with [Selection.containsNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode). Anyway, assuming that's possible, I'm afraid that looking for the exact word(s) includes working with coordinates and other dirty stuff...

Comment: Yeah the method I suggested was more psuedo-code than anything. And now that I think about it, it would only work if there was a guarantee to not be any duplicated words.